# how to find a specific pattern in a file in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am writing a Scala code to search for a specific file and in that file if the reg-ex matches it returns me that line .For simplicity i have written  a simple regular expression.
my code is

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.matching
object regex {
 println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

   val patter=""".*(BEGINNING).*""".r




   val dirName="/home/ugan/shaileshsir/20aug/temp.dwuKM/asup.txt"

 //var n=new 

 //for (filen <- nt){
try {
 for (line <- Source.fromFile(dirName).getLines()) {
   //println(line)
  line match
   {
   case patter(group) => group
    case _ => ""

   }
   println(line)
  }
} catch {
  case ex: Exception => println("Bummer, an exception happened.")
 }
```

Although `println(line)`  is working fine and it printing the file but i dont able to find the lines which is matched by regular expression.
Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is:

```
Source.fromFile(dirName).getLines().filter(_ matches ".*(BEGINNING).*")
```

If your regex is simply a `.*{Something}.*` you can consider also this:

```
Source.fromFile(dirName).getLines().filter(_ contains "(BEGINNING)")
```

Comment: ya i got the solution ,can you please suggest me how can i replace the matched string with any string in the file.?

Comment: please tell me one more thing, did you need to replace any matched line with an arbitrary constant string?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io._
object firstprogram {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val regex = ".*(BEGINNING).*".r
        val filename = "ScalaFile.txt"  
        var fileSource = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines  
        print(fileSource+"\n")
        for(x<-fileSource){
            var fileyo=x.replaceAll(".*(BEGINNING).*","x")
            val fileObject = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("ScalaFiletest1.txt"),true))   //true For appending
            val printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileObject)
            printWriter.write(fileyo+"\n")  // Writing to the new file  
            printWriter.close()
        }
    }
}
```